# thermux stops mariadb stops?

Tags: mysql

Thermux is a terminal emulator that allows to install and run Mariadb on Android. The emulator is based on Unix environment. It launches Maria db/mysql well. My kodi and the database may then coexist on the same android tvbox. Great.
If Thermux stops that should not affect Mariadb. Unfortunately this is what happening.
Any clue ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Was "mysqld" started as a "service"?

Comment: To further explain:
 1. I run mariadb on android 11 (tvbox 4gb Ram, 64 Rom Transpeed)  through Thermux emulator. 
 2. Mariadb is used to centralise info from Kodi. Each machine is then able to update info and share them
 3. 1 of the Kodi installs is run on the mentioned tvbox 

 4. According to the documentation once mariadb is started Thermux is not needed anymore and may be shut down at will.
 5. Though if I or the android shuts Thermux, Mariadb shuts down too. 
Does anyone may explain this and what is the solution to the problem ?
Thank you

Comment: To Rick James
Pertinent guess !! According to the instruction and docs the call mysqld safe already starts the service. Please suggest how I may check the service has started. Thank you very much.